# UIView appearance semanticContentAttribute for a specific view IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiview

I am using Localisation in my IOS App.There are two languages English and Arabic when we switch b/w languages layout is changed on the basis of language like RTL for the Arabic case and LTR for the English case

```
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

This changes the whole layout of the App.What i want is when the language is switched a specific view should not be flipped or just sticked to RTL in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it's constraint instead of leading make it left and instead of trailing make it right

uncheck respect language direction

[image: languageDir]